# Where is a list of special url types?

Tags: irc, url, apturl

I was looking in gconf-editor, and I say under url-handlers, all sorts of things before I thought had nothing to do with urls. I knew that you could do apt:package and irc:channel, but it had things like notes and trash. I had no idea that the internet could be so integrated into an operating system (while besides Google Chrome OS which is both an OS and a browser at the same time.) Does anyone know of a list of the various urls you can have. Is there such a thing as a url that executes any command at will! (Just imagine, no more just sending code to someone. You can send them a link to excute any command!)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there such a thing as a url that executes any command at will! (Just imagine, no more just sending code to someone. You can send them a link to excute any command!)

There is no such "default" url-handler. You could make one, of course, but it would be an **immense** security risk. Think Windows, where if you click on the link in one spam email, your computer could be infected with viruses or malware!

"executing any command" is even worse, say I sent you a hypothetical any-command-url called `anycommand:#rm -rf ~/#`, and you didn't know a lot about the command line or didn't notice, that would wipe out your entire home directory.

Always click on a url-handler with care :)

Comment: Indeed, custom protocol should be bound to fixed safe commands only, like opening a viewer, an editor, or a tool (which runs nothing by default when it starts and always prompt the user). An `anycommand:` protocol (I use to have one similar in the paste) can be OK, but only if it always prompt the user, with a clear display of the command, before running anything. Otherwise, it's fine to have custom URL protocols which run viewers or editors.